# Steam updating game that does not have DRM

Tags: steam, drm

At the moment [Good Old Games](http://www.gog.com/) have a special sale that has Witcher 2 enhanced edition.

If I get the game there which does not have DRM I don't think it will give me a key to activate it on Steam. So if there are updates on Steam then will the Witcher 2 be updated as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Steam does not manage updates for non-Steam games.  If there are updates, you will have to download them and install them yourself.

Comment: I am asking gog.com as well to see if they will provide me with a key to activate on steam else its just the game by itself.

Comment: if GOG provide you a steam key, it won't be a DRM-free copy of the game.